# Escaping inline code block in Asp.Net template

Tags: asp.net, templates, escaping, inline-code

I have a page where I wish to render the following html (a small JS template)-

```
<script type="text/html" id="lightbox-template">
 <div id="lightbox-background"></div>
 <div id="lightbox"><%= content %><div class="bottom"></div></div>
</script>
```

However, the Asp.NET preprocessor is picking up on the "<%=" tag and trying to interpret it. I wish to escape this tag to allow it to be rendered, preferably from the template rather than the code behind. Is this possible?

I have managed to do this via a Literal control and setting it's text in the code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ideally wanted to keep it within the aspx page. This is the best solution I could find ([from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z.aspx)), which creates splits the closing > into a separate string

```
<script type="text/html" id="lightbox-template">
 <div id="lightbox-background"></div>
 <div id="lightbox"><%= "<%= content %" + ">" %=><div class="bottom"></div></div>  
</script>
```

Important bit: **<%= "<%= content %" + ">" %=>**

Comment: That's horrible though!  I think it would be better to change the settings on your JS template tool, to use other markers.

Comment: Agreed. And by doing this it made the templates a lot less readable to a non-Asp.Net developer. However, it was a custom template tool, with no option to change the markers, and this was the quickest solution.

Answer (score -1):

This goes into aspx

```
<div> <%= GetContentString() %>  </div>
```

This goes into aspx.cs

```
 protected String GetContentString()
    {
        return "this is a content";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but ideally I wanted to keep it within the aspx page. I could also put it into the aspx.cs page using a literal control.