# "<%=value%>" in javascript not ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, chart.js

I started using chartjs and i can specify options where the code looks like this:

```
legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
```

The thing is that <% %> is interpreted as ASP.NET code. How can I avoid the conflict?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping inline code block in Asp.Net template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654747/escaping-inline-code-block-in-asp-net-template)

Comment: answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25506542/2737978

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in a string, kind of like escaping it.

The close tag doesn't seem to work, so you could concatenate two strings, and use constants to make it slightly easier to read:

```
<%
     const string OPEN = "<%=";
     const string CLOSE = "%" + ">";
%>

legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=OPEN%>name.toLowerCase()<%=CLOSE%>-legend...
```

Or do it in javascript instead, but this would make it more difficult to see in the source HTML:

```
    var OPEN = "<" + "%" + "=";
    var CLOSE = "%" + ">";

    legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"" + OPEN + "name.toLowerCase()" + CLOSE + "-legend... "
```

Another option would be to use a different representation for one of the characters, maybe for percent. You could do `\045` or another representation (**EDIT**: Don't use `\045`, use `\x25` or `\u0025` instead - looks like octal is getting phased out of javascript):

```
legendTemplate = "<ul class=\"<\x25=name.toLowerCase()\x25>-legend... "
```

Or probably the better answer, if you're not using any server code in this particular piece of javascript, just move it out to a .js file.

Comment: What is this type of code called? Is it just for chartjs or is it standard JavaScript?

Comment: If you're talking about `\045`, that's just the [character-escaped value](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#octal) for the `%` character (backslash followed by the octal number. octal-45 is decimal-37, which is the ASCII code for that character). It's the same as `\u0025` or `\x25` - I just happened to be looking at the octal column of my ASCII chart when I wrote that. But as I'm reading that article I just linked to, I'd actually probably go with the `\x` or `\u` instead - the octal rules are a little screwy.